# Is it possible to generate attribute with Enum parameter via Roslyn

Tags: c#, enums, roslyn, code-analysis

I would like to generate custom attribute that receives Enum parameter value. So far, I've managed to create one with a string parameter but I'm completely lost about enumeration management in Roslyn API, and lack of samples in the documentation does not help, of course.

My working example:

```
    return SyntaxFactory.AttributeList(
                SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(
                    SyntaxFactory.Attribute(
                        SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("TestAttribute"),
                        SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgumentList(
                            SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(
                                new[]
                                {
                                    SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgument(
                                        SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(
                                            SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(
                                                "TestEnum.SomeValue"))))

                                }
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

Using this snippet allows me to get this result:

```
[TestAttribute("TestEnum.SomeValue")]        
public void SomeMethod() {}
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
[TestAttribute(TestEnum.SomeValue)]      // Enum instead of string  
public void SomeMethod() {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return SyntaxFactory.AttributeList(
        SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(
            SyntaxFactory.Attribute(
                SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("TestAttribute"),
                SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgumentList(
                    SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(
                        new[]
                        {
                            SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgument(
                                SyntaxFactory.MemberAccessExpression(
                                    SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression, 
                                    SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("TestEnum"),
                                    SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.DotToken),
                                    SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("SomeValue")
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```